# how to generate models class table and views all for existing oracle database using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I was able to create a table but still lack views.
Working with ASP.NET CORE EF, I have generated model classes from existing database with following command:
`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source =localhost:1521/Xe;User Id = username; Password = root;" Oracle.Entityframeworkcore -o Models --context-dir Context -c OracleDbContext`

Answer (score 0):

You sort of can not. The EfCore generator is extremely limited and does not support a lot of elements. SOme thigns are just not supported, including Stored Procedures, IIRC. Note that this is only code generation - EntityFramework (Core) has no problem calling them.

That is highly inconvenient.

I have long given up on him and am using DevArt EntityDeveloper instead - graphicsl UI (db diagrams) and support for also stored procedures. The EntityFramework version is quite cheap.

Comment: So I have to switch to DevArt EntityDeveloper to get the most out of the EF Core.

Comment: Nope, you have to use a third party tool for your CONVENIENCE. You can also write all the code yourself.